Django pre-signed url file uploads architecture MVC
I'm trying to implement file uploads using pre-signed URLs using Django. I've got the upload part working, however, I'm not sure what the architecture should look like for standard MVC application.
Assume this model:
    class Document(models.Model): 
       file = models.FileField()
       extra_field = models.CharField()




Render GET page with file upload form.

User modifies <input type='file'> and the browser makes a request to /api/get-presigned-url which returns PUT URL for file upload

Browser uploads a document to PUT URL.


These 3 steps are clear. The next steps are completely unclear and I'm not sure how to then save this already uploaded document to my Document model.
If I submit the form with Filefield set - the file is uploaded into server-side which we're trying to avoid using pre-signed URLs.
If I modify the form to have file_url and set it to pre-signed PUT URL - it works but it's not secure as user can just modify the file name and access any file in the bucket.
What would be the recommended architecture for using pre-signed URLs with Django standard MVC pattern with GET/POST requests.

Off the top of my head: when requesting the presigned URL, store some record of that in your server. Hook up an S3 event notification, so your server gets notified about new uploads to your bucket. When the file appears in your bucket, check the record you have already created for that file. This way your server controls the entire process.
